# Avro schema specification won't take same namespace

Tags: schema, avro

I defined a schema that goes by :

```
{ "namespace":"configschemas.avro",
  "type":"record",
  "name":"pathObject",
  "fields":
  [
    {   "name":"pathString", 
        "type" : "string", 
        "default" : "null"
    }
    ,
    {   "name":"needsConversion",
         "type" : "boolean" ,
          "default" : false
    }
    ]
}
```

The second schema won't compile after compiling the above schema.

```
{ "namespace" : "configschemas.avro",
  "type" : "array" , 
  "items" : configschemas.avro.pathObject
}
```

All the schemas are under the same directory and the namespaces are same as well. Can't get the flaw.

Error while compiling second schema:

```
Input files to compile:
  logPaths.avsc
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): expected a vali
d value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: logPaths.avsc; line: 3, column: 13]
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:967)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:932)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.SpecificCompilerTool.run(SpecificCompilerTool.java:73)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:84)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false
' or 'null')
 at [Source: logPaths.avsc; line: 3, column: 13]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2090)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:555)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:192)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1344)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:965)
        ... 4 more**
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain how you're invoking the schema parser, but putting both schemas in the same schema file should work, as this demonstrates

```java
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.avro', module='avro', version='1.7.7')
])

import org.apache.avro.Schema;

String schema = '''
{
  "namespace":"configschemas.avro",
  "type":"record",
  "name":"pathObject",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"pathString", 
      "type":"string", 
      "default":"null"
    },
    {
      "name":"needsConversion",
      "type":"boolean",
      "default":false
    }
  ]
}

{
  "namespace":"configschemas.avro",
  "type":"array", 
  "items":configschemas.avro.pathObject
}'''

try {
    System.out.println(new Schema.Parser().parse(schema));
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

So if you either load all schemas in a namespace together, it should work (you can keep them in separate files, just load the text from the files together).